# Обновление фрагмента после закрытия Activity

Tags: android

У меня такая ситуация, есть фрагмент с данными из него вызывается диалоговое окно с вариантами выбора, а из него уже Activity. Как сделать так, что бы после закрытия activity фрагмент обновлялся?

Comment: Когда открывается новая Activity, то у фрагмента должн onPause сработать. Соответственно после закрытия Activity во фрагменте должен сработать метод onResume

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать собственный колбэк, который будет срабатывать в фрагменте при закрытии активити. Принцип действия аналогичен колбэку `onActivityResult()`, но им вы воспользоваться не можете, поскольку вызываете активити не из этого фрагмента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во фрагмете опишите логику обновления в onResume.